# How do I achieve a fast OpenCV uniformity detection image processing algorithm?

Tags: java, performance, opencv, image-processing

I desire an image processing function that returns a 1 for each pixel if all the pixels around it (say +/- 4) have the nearly the same RGB values (to within some threshold: epsilon).  Otherwise, zero is returned in the pixel location.

I have written this using `get()` and `put()`, and with the Java API, sweeping over the entire image matrix, but it is very slow.

Is there some tactic I can use to leverage existing OpenCV image processing functions to achieve the same result but much faster?

Answer (score 1):

What about [Inrange()](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#inrange) function in opencv?. I think it will satisfy your condition.

Comment: I'm attempting to detect surfaces that are of relatively constant value, but I don't necessarily know the value ahead of time.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of implemented and well known functions it is a question about algorithm, not language. Try this with you initial image(matrix) r-channel for A:

- calc Amin -- result of windowed(window half-size = 4) min operation on A called "erosion"
- calc Asub-min = A - Amin
- threshold Asub-min by epsilon ( if(Asub_ij < epsilon) Asub_ij = 1 else Asub_ij = 0 ), let's call result Asub-min-thr.
- do the same for max function ("dilation")
- Ares = Asub-min-thr AND Asub-max-thr -- Ares is answer for one channel
- do the same for all channels
- Ares-rgb = Ares-r AND Ares-g AND Ares-b -- your final answer.

All functions above are [well implemented](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html) [in openCV](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/erosion_dilatation/erosion_dilatation.html), including GPU acceleration (GPU not always reachable from Java). No more get() and put() at all!

If you need not per channel epsilon-distance but L2 distance in RGB, you will have to do more calculations like Asub-rgb^2 = Asub-r*Asub-r + Asub-g*Asub-g + Asub-b*Asub-b  and then epsilon^2 thresholding, but for 3-dimensional RGB space per-channel epsilon differs from L2-epsilon just by factor sqrt(3) in **worst** case so you may ignore it and do fast calculation.